# How to iterate on form array member in c# server (client is Extjs form)

Tags: forms, c#-4.0, extjs

In the server I get my arrays as such string:
0:val1,1:val2,2:val3

I work with NameValueCollection but this iterates through all the form members.
How do I parse\iterate through array form member to get a neat array of
{"val1","val2","val3"} without its index?

BTW - the client was sent with ExtJs Form submit...(maybe its something in the client?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful such an array could be if you can't map the value to its property, but try this:

```
var values[];

Ext.each(form.getForm().items, function (field) {
    values.push(field.getValue());
}, this);

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'backend.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        values: Ext.JSON.encode(values)
    },
    success: function(response){

        // process server response here
    }
});
```